# Configuring PhpStorm to use Pug-PHP

Tags: php, pug, phpstorm

I'm testing [pug-php](https://github.com/pug-php/pug) (with [laravel-pug](https://github.com/BKWLD/laravel-pug)) for use in a future project.

I'm using PHP expression syntax (I prefer it to JS expression syntax), but Pug plugin for PhpStorm is only for JS Syntax.

Can I configure PhpStorm for use PHP syntax and recognize PHP function like `strtoupper($str)`.

This capture show errors and warnings marked by the IDE, but it code compile fine.

[image: Errors and warnings marked by the IDE]

Comment: Unlikely/No. I mean -- the plugin (Parser part) should be aware of such syntax (so it can build proper structure of the code) in order to tell IDE that it is an acceptable one .. otherwise IDE will say "what is this?" and will show warnings/errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for pug-php in PhpStorm at the moment. We also did not receive any requests for this so it would be great if you could submit the feature request to our tracking system here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes.
You will be able to receive the answer directly from our developers while other users will be able to write their opinion of your proposal.

Comment: Thanks you! I'll write it tonight (UTC) and post here as comment the link of  the issue.

Comment: I opened [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36654) in your system.